# Is it possible to obtain a set of the Mann Co. Supply Crate Keys?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a few crates in my inventory that I would like to open. I wondered if it was possible to have a pack of keys? I am not talking about trading. I'm talking about one item that gives me X keys. With sets, usually, the price is cheaper.

I also wondered if there was a better time to another to get the keys. Is it be possible to obtain special? If so, is there a time of year in particular, or should I check the store frequently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, keys are gotten one at a time, and they don't drop through the game's drop system.

If you want keys, you're going to have to buy them, trade for them, or hope Miss Pauling gives everyone a free key like she did last year around the December holidays.

During the Australian Christmas event; Summer Sale; and Australian Christmas 2011 event, special keys were sold that only opened special holiday or summer themed crates.  They were sold for the same price as normal keys and reverted to normal keys when the holiday/summer crates expired.

Comment: Updated answer slightly with a note about the current holiday have new keys.